# How is Groovy hot-swap agent "gragent.jar" is supposed to work in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

It seems doesn't add anything to the regular java hot-swapping. I'd like to get the groovy class hot-swapped in a case of method adding/removing/signature changing. Is it possible with this agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dany's answer is correct, but doesn't answer the question fully. No, this agent doesn't help you to hot-swap when fields or methods are changed. You might want to consider using [DCEVM](https://dcevm.github.io/) for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Removes all timestamp-related Groovy fields on class loading
>   Also clears Groovy's call site cache

As stated in
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/groovy/hotswap/agentSrc/org/groovy/debug/hotswap/ResetAgent.java